# firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) hang on mobile devices

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement FB login on my ionic 2 app. It works perfectly on web, but when I build the android version and install it onto my mobile, the fbLogin function will just cause the app to hang. I tried to build live version, but it doesn't solve the hang problem.

```
facebookLogin(){
   var facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
   return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(facebook);
}
```

Comment: If this is an ionic/cordova mobile app, you should use signInWithRedirect and follow the steps explained here to get it working as expected: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Comment: Hi Bojeil, Thanks for your help. It solved my problem now.